# ASP.NET MVC - WCF Classes for Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET | MVC 4 | C# | WCF

I am using WCF web services as an intermediary from the presentation layer (MVC) to the data layer (Entity). To simplify moving data model data from MVC to the web service I thought I would use proxy classes in WCF, so that there would be one centralized class. Unfortunately, this caused the loss of MVC decorations on properties within the model. Is there a good way to create a centralized class for use with a model for the MVC view, and also as a transport method to the WCF service?

Automapping came to mind as an option, but I believe that would require two identical classes. One on the MVC side and one on the WCF side. Which would still require me to make a change on both sides if a property changed in a class.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:: Example**

Here is model for a page that contains a table of records

```
public class ReconcileModel
{
    #region PROPERTIES

    public List<ReconcileItem> ReconcileItems { get; set;}

    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    public ReconcileModel()
    {
        ReconcileItems = new List<ReconcileItem>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is a class to represent each record in that table.

```
public class ReconcileItem
{
    #region PROPERTIES

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LastLocation { get; set; }
    public string LastRead { get; set; }
    public string IntendenLocation { get; set; }
    public string PickId { get; set; }
    public string OEM { get; set; }
    public string LotNumber { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public string ReconcileReason { get; set; }
    public string RemoveReason { get; set; }


    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    public ReconcileItem()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The WCF contract representation of the class above would be

```
[DataContract]
public class ReconcileItem
{
    [DataMemeber]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastLocation { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastRead { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string IntendenLocation { get; set; }
    [DataMemeber]
    public string PickId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OEM { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LotNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ReconcileReason { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RemoveReason { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to update this record, the class is sent to the WCF service, mapped to appropriate entity framework classes, and saved to the database. To simplify the transfer I thought I would just put this class in the WCF project and reference it in the MVC project. Then I could pass the class back in forth between WCF and MVC. Also, if I updated the class in WCF then it would be reflected in MVC. That's what is meant by centralized.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you present us with some code, for instance showing what you mean by 'centralized class'?

Comment: @Steven see edits and let me know if that clarifies things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Adrian, I question whether you actually need a WCF service between your DB and an MVC service. This is a much more likely scenario for a client application (Win Forms, WPF) that talks to a database. I'm currently working on a Win Forms project where we use WCF as intermediate layer and we do the following:

- We have an assembly (called 'contract') that is shared between the client and the WCF / BL.
- This 'contract' assembly contains all DTOs that are sent over the wire by and to WCF.
- We configured the WCF client proxy to use the contract assembly (instead of letting WCF regenerate all DTOs) by setting the 'Reuse types in specified reference assemblies' in the Service Reference Settings.
- We decorate those DTOs with DataAnnotations attributes (and other metadata).
- We **don't** decorate those DTOs with WCF attributes. WCF doesn't need them to serialize DTOs. They are **optional**. Leave them out if you can. It just clutters your code.
- Since the client uses the same assembly we can use DataAnnotations on the client.
- We validate on the server as well.
- We use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.codeplex.com/) to do most of the boilerplate mapping from entities to DTOs (but never the other way around).
- To be frank, you don't even let WCF serialize our DTOs, but use [JSON.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) and WCF just send and receive (plain text) JSON, because JSON.NET is simply so much more flexible when it comes to serializing and deserializing data structures. For instance, we use JSON.NET to (de)serialize immutable object structures. Try that with WCF. That will fail miserably.

On top of that we do:

- The use of View Model classes to add client functionality.
- Add custom DataAnnotation validations in the contract assembly to allow validations to run on both the client and the server.
- Add an `IValidator<T>` abstraction (of some sort) to allow either server or client specific validations (by placing implementations in either your business layer or client application).
- Transport server specific validation errors back to the client using exceptions.

Comment: thanks for your post, it was very informative. Essentially I was thinking of making the ViewModel classes the DTO. Automapping those classes to a WCF class and then using the Controller to pass the class to a WCF method for adding/updating/deleting. Is there an advantage to putting these in a "contract" assembly as you described? Rather than just defining them in WCF?

Comment: If you don't put them in their own assembly and share that assembly between server and client, it means that Visual Studio must generate a client proxy for you and will regenerate your DTO on the client. Not only will this cause you to have a shitload of extra (generated) code, VS will *never* regenerate any attributes (such as DataAnnotations attributes) on the client. In other words: you will loose all the metadata you defined on those DTOs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your Entities still, but create View Models and put your data annotations on these instead.  There's a lot of talk about where to put validation in a project.  In general it's almost always a given that it needs to occur at the UI and then usually elsewhere too.  I'd avoid trying to centralise it, as this never works out (one size rarely fits all).

On the subject of wedging a WCF layer **within** your solution, unless there is a very good reason for it, I would avoid doing this at all costs.  I've seen this sort of thing go wrong many times.  It brings a lot of negative effects.  In the two commercial cases I have dealt with, you end up with too many endpoints and too much chattiness.  It cripples being able to put business logic in your entities and use those methods over-the-wire, makes maintenance a nightmare and without enough hardware and careful design, if hosted on a single server, you may end up having to use named pipes to get the speed you need, which negates any distributed advantage you'd get from using WCF.

You would be best to externalise heavy processing tasks as components that you can host elsewhere and communicate through a smaller, more concise interface.  In reality apart from image processing, mathematical and scientific applications, heavy data processing doesn't crop up.

Comment: I would also add that there is a security risk in exposing WCF classes as MVC models.

Comment: The idea of WCF in between is that the MVC would be used only for presentation. When the fields on the page were updated and saved; the class would be populated and sent to the WCF to be manipulated and saved to the database. Now the question is if that is an ideal way to do it. We want to have each service be responsible for a set of tables in the database, so data always flows through those services if its added/updated/deleted.

Comment: @Will that sounds good, in the cases where I've seen internal WCF layers cause issues, it's always been due to the layer exposing as many methods as it would if it was just an assembly.  With careful crafting of the WCF layer, in theory it could/should work.  What you'd probably end up with is a WCF layer that returns a full set (almost view model) of everything needed to display a particular page in a single call.  This would then make it easy to bolt on a mobile phone app presentation layer later.  I'd just be mindful of keeping business logic out of any of the layers above the WCF layer.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips, you're correct. I would essentially be returning the view model. Which would get automapped to a class in MVC just so I can preserve the MVC decorations in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

We use WCF in the manner you describe in your post at my current employer. We ended up having DTO classes for WCF and MVC to communicate with and then ViewModels within the MVC application for model binding and validation within the UI.

I agree that having classes that are nearly duplicates of one another and mapping between them is a pain and just seems wrong at some level. From what I've read in the past what we did, and what you may be forced to do, is best practice.

What Adrian proposed above with regard to only having heavy processing done by WCF makes sense as well. Prior to starting my current job I did just that. Most of the business logic was placed in a business layer assembly directly reference by the MVC application. For the few potentially long running processes there were I created WCF services hosted separately that the MVC application communicated with.

Lastly, could you use Web API vs WCF? Web API is lightweight and utilizes HTTP with out all of the overhead that comes with WCF bindings, etc. Additionally, with Web API you could use the same classes the MVC application is using and even utilize model validation within the Web API. This is something I've been working on and becoming more and more common.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Mapping duplicate classes seems wrong to me as well, but like you said it seems to be best practice. I wasn't aware of WebAPI until just now. Unfortunately, our services are TCP bindings, but WebAPI may be useful on some of my other projects.